# Duda uso basename

Tags: php

Estoy analizando un código que funciona correctamente pero tengo una duda ¿Por qué en esta línea se usa `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` y después se le da la función basename? Según yo entiendo la primera ($_FILES...) devuelve el nombre fichero con la extensión sin la ruta. Por otra parte basename hace lo mismo ¿Por que se usan las dos juntas haciendo lo mismo?

```
$target_file = $carpeta . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Comment: [basename](http://php.net/manual/es/function.basename.php) lo que hace es devolver el ultimo nombre de la direccion  ejemplo : `/tmp/files/chispas.jpg` devolvera `chispas.jpg` luego tiene $carpeta (asumo que previamente tiene la ruta destino) y lo concatena , mas adelante en el codigo debe estar el `move` y alli estara el archivo (si cuenta con los permisos suficientes

Comment: Si, entiendo lo que hace basename pero lo que no entiendo es que $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] hace lo mismo. ¿Por que entonces no se pondría simplemente $target_file = $carpeta . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]; que devuelve lo  mismo? ¿por qué deben ponerse ambos?